# Auth::attempt($credentials) always return false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Each time I am trying to connect to my API using Postman I am getting credentials as false eventhough there are the same that in the database.

I tried to change the size of the password column in the database to 60.
I printed the credentials to check if they were correct.

**AuthController**

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

**auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'gestionnaires',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'clients',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'gestionnaires' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Gestionnaire::class,
    ],

    'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**Model**

```
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login')->name('login');
```

Comment: Why are you not sending a request to `/oauth/token`? Please read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#issuing-access-tokens) on issuing access tokens.

Comment: I will reread the documenation thanks. By the way I forgot to mention that when I am using the same model (users, gestionnaires, clients) for every providers in the guards the authentication work fine. It's only when web and api providers are differents that the issue arise.

Comment: I see now that you are using a different model, `App\Client`. Are you positive that this model is configured correctly per the docs?

Comment: I took the User model and past it in my Client model.

Comment: Ok, did you add `protected $table = 'users';`?

Comment: You mean on my models ? Yes, I tried with and without this on every model (ex:  model Client, `protected $table = 'clients';`) but nothing change. I have noticed something weird. Even if the provider in the api guard is `clients` I can use Postman to do a post with the credentials of the table in the web guards (table: gestionnaires) but I cannot do that with the credentials of the clients table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$credentials = [
 'email' => $request->email,
 'password' => $request->password
 ];
  if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Unauthorized'
    ], 401);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

My model look like this which is quite similar to the `user` model.

```
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```